Am trying to add different background images to different pages in my react application, can anyone help me with that?
Initially I have set the background image of my first page 'login.jsx' and when it navigates to another page 'verification.jsx' the background image of the other page is not sizing up to the entire webpage, have tried varoius css styling to have different background image for different pages but it didn't work, can anyone help me with this issue...
this is the login.jsx file
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import './Login.css';
import bg from '../../assets/login-background.png';

function Login() {
  let [uname, setUname] = useState("");
  let [pwd, setPwd] = useState("");
  const nav = useNavigate();

  const validate = () => {
    console.log(uname, pwd);
    if(uname.toLowerCase() === 'aisu' && pwd.toLowerCase() === 'aisu') {
      nav('/verification');
    } else {
      nav('/');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <br />
      <div className="form-title">Login</div>
      <div className="form-fields">
        <label>username : </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="username"
          value={uname}
          onChange={(event) => setUname(event.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <br />
        <label>password : </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="password"
          value={pwd}
          onChange={(event) => setPwd(event.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <br />
        <button onClick={validate}> login </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;


and this is the login.css file
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Lobster|Chewy|Anton|Shadows+Into+Light|Open+Sans|Roboto|Orbitron|Oswald|Raleway|Montserrat|Roboto+Slab|Indie+Flower|Fjalla+One|Bree+Serif|Pacifico|Abril+Fatface);

body {
    background-image: url('../../assets/login-background.png');
    background-size: 1640px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    
}

.form-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(6, 6, 27, 0.322);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px black;    
}

.form-title {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    font-family:'Pacifico';
    font-size: 42px;
}

label {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
}

input {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 70px;
}

button:hover {
    color: rgb(229, 91, 137);
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px 2px rgb(243, 135, 171);
}


the verification.jsx page is as follows
import React from 'react';
import './Verification.css';

function Verification() {
  return (
    <body class='verification'>
      <div>Verification</div>
    </body>
    
  )
}

export default Verification;

and the verification.css page is as follows
body.verification {
    background-color: aqua;
    background-size: 1640px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/593655/pexels-photo-593655.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-jovana-nesic-188639-593655.jpg&fm=jpg');
    
}

tried various css styling such as changing the background size position etc but was unable to fix the issue.
